# Is there a way to display a html grid

Tags: html, grid

Everybody knows how a dropdown menu works where a person clicks on the drop down menu and it displays a drop down list where the user can select an option from the list. What I want to know is that is there a way in html where except displaying a dropdown list can I display a grid instead with the options in the grid?  I havn't got any code for this but if anyone knows this is possible and can provide an example of this I would be very greatful and it would be very helpful.

Comment: I think it is a bit impossible to understand what you want to do.

Comment: Uh...you can control what ever you want to show as a drop down, make a table in drop down and viola

Comment: Are you looking for something similar to one of these controls in http://www.northcantonschools.org/tech/images/stories/faq-pics/google_documents/insert_table.gif or this http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/controls/colorpicker-controls-for-winforms/ColorPicker.jpg?

Comment: @Micah Yes I am, that is exactly what I am looking for, do you know how this is done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a basic example:

http://jsfiddle.net/QmLmC/

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div id="myDropdownGrid" class="dropdownGrid">
    <div>
        <button type="button">Open/Close</button>
    </div>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<p>Click the button above to view open or close the grid.</p>
```

.

```
/* CSS */
.dropdownGrid{position:relative;}
.dropdownGrid table{position:absolute; z-index:999; display:none;}
.dropdownGrid td{width:20px; height:20px; background-color:white;}
.dropdownGrid td:hover{background-color:blue;}
```

.

```
// Javascript using jQuery
$("#myDropdownGrid button").click( function(){    
    $('#myDropdownGrid table').toggle();

});
```

Comment: Let me just thank you for this basic example and for you putting your time to help me. I will use this example as a stepping stone for what I want to acheive, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

... well, there's no such thing as a 'grid' but a table would present the info in 'grid' form. You could build a grid out of div elements, but that can get unduly tedious.

Feel like using jQuery for this?

```
/* make  button clickable */
$("#someButton").click( function(){
   /* grid like container of data, talbe or a complex div 'structure' */
   $("#someGrid").toggle() // if grid is visible hide it, if hidden show it

})
```

... so you'd have a button with an id of "someButton" and whatever grid structure/wrapper with id id of "someGrid" and css of "display:none" on it.